# Facebook login image in server side implementation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I suspect that there's a simple answer to this, but since I'm stumped, let me throw this out there.

I am implementing a "Login with Facebook" feature for a website. Facebook allows ways to do most of the work either on the server or the client side. We have opted for the former.

So, the link that a user clicks on to initiate the login looks like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream
```

My simple question: I want the user to click the familiar "Login with Facebook" image to get directed to this URL. I cannot use the `<fb:login-button>` since that initiates the javascript based authentication and login. So, basically, I want a link that looks like:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream"><img Login with Facebook image goes here /></a>`

How do I get the image as a link in my server side implementation? Or, do I pretty much have to handle the login on the client side using `<fb:login-button>` if I want Facebook to automatically generate the image?  (By the way, I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.5.)

Comment: Has anyone found a solution meanwhile?

Comment: That's a reasonable and logical question, but Facebook doesn't offer a solution:(

Answer (score 5):

You should either use your own image (or other markup) to represent the login button or use one of the [Facebook logos from "Brand Permissions Center"](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php).

There is another option too... If you include JS-SDK on page you can use the following markup to get a button that looks exactly like the one in [Login Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) social plugin:

```
<a class="fb_button fb_button_small">
  <span class="fb_button_text">Log In</span>
</a>
```

**Update:** 
Using custom markup instead of `fb:login-button` will require additional work for sure.

For translation of text on button you can use [Facebook internationalization](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/), [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) or any other technology/technique you're familiar with...

Regarding the Auth you'll need for sure add `href` attribute pointing to [OAuth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) (for server-side flow. You already have this one in question itself) or bind JavaScript click event that will call [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) (for client-side flow).

Comment: This is a good answer in general, but it doesn't allow for translating the button text into other languages which was specifically mentioned.

Comment: The translation can be done server-side - with, for example, gettext. The problem is it covers the "implicit flow", and not server side authentication...

Comment: @MarcoS, nothing in question or bounty description say it should cover server-side auth, if providing link to OAuth dialog is called coverage than it's already covered by question itself

Answer (score 1):

You have to put manually facebook login button. Facebook doesn't offer image button for manually login button. You can get facebook login button from this site.:

-[login_button](https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/login_input.htm)

They have same functionality like you.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream"><img class='facebookLoginBtn'/></a>
```

And copy their css and image.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

In Html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="facebookLogin()">
     <img Login with Facebook image goes here />
</a>
```

In Javascript:

```
function facebookLogin() {
     FB.init({ appId: 'AppId ', xfbml: true, cookie: true, frictionlessRequests: true });
     FB.login(function (response) {
         if (response.authResponse) {
              //Login
         }
         else {
              //Not Login
         }
     }, { scope: 'email' });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkward, but the best way I know of to handle this is to use `<fb:login-button>` to generate the button, and then use css to position an empty div directly on top of it.  Then you can attach on onclick handler to the div that will redirect to the url of your choice.  The div will need to be sized to approximately the height and width of the button which you don't know for certain in advance, but you can either just go for "close enough", or do some javascript to set the div size dynamically after the button is rendered.  In most cases a login button doesn't overlap other elements so no one will notice if the clickable area is a bit bigger than the button itself.

Edit: Some code samples will probably make this clearer.  First the fixed size version, which will probably work for most cases:

```
<div style="position:relative">
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:70px;height:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream'"></div>
</div>
```

And also a dynamic size version, which should work but hasn't been tested in all browsers:

```
<span style="position:relative">
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream"><span style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;font-size:200px;overflow:hidden">&nbsp;</span></a>
</span>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer (though I decided to go with client-side....),  because it covers the server-type login. It deserves the bounty...

Comment: And you possibly violate [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) using this. Citing IV.4.d `You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin.` It's not clear enough if other social plugins affected by this...

Comment: I don't believe that there is any violation here. The reference is about "obscuring" a social plugin, and although it uses the word "cover" I think it certainly refers to hiding the element (presumably for deceptive purposes).  Although there's some ambiguity in the wording, I can't believe that using the login button plugin to initiate a server-side login (i.e. still using the button to do exactly what it says and what a user would expect) could be considered any kind of violation.  Just my opinion, of course.

Answer (score 0):

i use a simple href link to loging with facebook, then i use some css to put the image button i like or maybe you can use a image link as allways.

```
<div class="signupBtn"><a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"><span>Enter</span></a></div>

<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"> <img src="your image here"> </a>
```

The $loginUrl it will buil the url for you if you use the facebook php sdk.